# Localisation in Asp.Net Core 3.1 not working after updatig from versin 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

We had a website in Asp.net core version 2.2.
We have updated the website from version 2.2 to 3.1.

The same code we were using for the localization in version 2.2 is not working after updating the application to version 3.1.

I have put the code on [github.com/gurpreet42/MyAppV3](https://github.com/gurpreet42/MyAppV3). Please check and suggest changes.

Following section shows the startup.cs file content

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

 services.AddSingleton<LocService>();

 services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

            services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
            {
                var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
                                            {
                                                new CultureInfo("en-US"),
                                                new CultureInfo("nl")
                                            };

                options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US");
                options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
                options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
            });

            services.AddMvc()
               .AddViewLocalization()
               .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(options =>
               {
                   options.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (type, factory) =>
                   {
                       var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(typeof(SharedResource).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.FullName);
                       return factory.Create("SharedResource", assemblyName.Name);
                   };
               }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

}


public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app,
                        IHostingEnvironment env,
                        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    //Localisation
    var locOptions = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
    app.UseRequestLocalization(locOptions.Value);

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseSession();

    app.UseSession();
    app.UseCookiePolicy();
}
```

The code in the LocService class is

```
public class LocService
{
    private readonly IStringLocalizer _localizer;

    public LocService(IStringLocalizerFactory factory)
    {
        var type = typeof(SharedResource);
        var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(type.GetTypeInfo().Assembly.FullName);
        _localizer = factory.Create("SharedResource", assemblyName.Name);
    }

    public LocalizedString GetLocalizedHtmlString(string key)
    {
        var value= _localizer[key];
        return value;
    }
}
```

Now on our controller, we can access the localized string as

```
localizerService.GetLocalizedHtmlString("my_string")
```

Under the "Resources" folder we have following files present

1. SharedResource.cs
2. SharedResource.en-US.resx
3. SharedResource.nl.resx

After updating the website from .net core version 2.2 to version 3.1 the values are not getting converted to the selected language.

Comment: Can you show the `startup.cs` for v3.1?

Comment: @LazZiya I have edited the post show to mention the content of startup.cs

Comment: It is still not working. 
can you please check the demo application created by me and suggest what I am doing wrong there
https://github.com/gurpreet42/MyAppV3
How can I make this working.

Answer (score 0):

`startup.cs` file still pointing v2.2 and using some deprected features as I noticed.

I just updated the `startup` to use v3.1 and it worked fine:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<LocService>();

    services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

    services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
    {
        var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
                                    {
                                        new CultureInfo("en-US"),
                                        new CultureInfo("nl")
                                    };

        options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US");
        options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
        options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
    });

    services.AddRazorPages()
        .AddViewLocalization()
        .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(options =>
        {
            options.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (type, factory) =>
            {
                var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(typeof(SharedResource).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.FullName);
                return factory.Create("SharedResource", assemblyName.Name);
            };
        });
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    var locOptions = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
    app.UseRequestLocalization(locOptions.Value);

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    });
}
```

Comment: @GurpreetKailey, glad to know it is working. Doing more changes depends on what you want to achieve. In general there is a lot to do for fully localizing ASP.Net Core web app (Views, DataAnnotations, ModelBinding, IdentityErrors, Client side validation...etc). For more details you may see the [official docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-3.1). Additionally [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5061604/Developing-Multicultural-ASP-NET-Core-3-2-1-Projec) can help you have an overall idea and do localization faster and easier.

Comment: In last comment It was a typo, Actually It is not working. 
can you please check the demo application created by me and make it working.
https://github.com/gurpreet42/MyAppV3

Comment: Thanks @LazZiya for your help, we are able to find the root cause.